# Extreme values using Taylor Expansion.

Tags: taylor-expansion

- The n:th derivative of $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood around a point $b$
- $f^{'}(b)=f^{''}(b)=...=f^{(n-1)}(b)=0$
- $f^{(n)}(b)\neq 0 $

From the conditions above I am supposed to come to the following conclusions:

- $n\ even\ \land f^{n}(b)<0 \implies f$ has strict maxima in $b$
- $n\ even\ \land f^{n}(b)>0 \implies f$ has strict minima in $b$
- $n\ odd \implies f$ has no extreme in $b$

My attempt is based on Taylor's formula:

$f(x) = f(b) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {f^{(k)}(b)}{k!} (x-b)^{k} + R_{n}(x) \iff f(x)-f(b)= R_{n}(x)$

$R_{n}(x)$ is the Lagrange remainder $\iff R_{n}(x) = \frac {f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))}{n!} \ (x-b)^{n}$ , $0<c<1$

So $f(x)-f(b) = \frac {f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))}{n!} \ (x-b)^{n}$

I stuck here and would appreciate some hints/tips on how to carry forward.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

By Taylor-Young formula, we can write

$$f(b+h)-f(b)=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{h^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(b)+\frac{h^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(b)\epsilon(h)$$

$$=\frac{h^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(b)\Bigl(1+\epsilon(h)\Bigr)$$

with $$\lim_{h\to 0}\epsilon(h)=0$$
and for small $ h $ we have $1+\epsilon(h)>0$.

Comment: I suppose with $h = x-b$, I can get $f^{(n)}(b+c \ (x-b)))$ to $f^{(n)} (b+c h)$ , but how can I justify the step towards it being equal to $f^{(n)}(b) + f^{(n)} * c * h$ ?